# At what rate is the price rising given the following information?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

At item costs $200$ dollars at $t=0$ and costs $P$ in year $t$. When the inflation is $r\%$ per year, the price is given by

$$\displaystyle P = 200e^{\Large \frac{r t}{100}}$$

If $r$ increases at a rate of $.2$ per year, when $r=4$ and $t=3$, at what rate is the price rising (in dollars per year)?

I took the derivative of the equation and I got

$$\displaystyle \frac {dP}{dt}=  200 e^{\Large \frac{rt}{100}} \times \frac{t}{100} \times \frac{dr}{dt}.$$

I assumed that $t$ was constant but I am not really sure? I kept getting a wrong answer of $1.2e^{3/25}$. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: It really helps readability if you format your questions using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, please make sure I edited everything properly. Regards

Answer (score 1):

The problem *says* that $\frac{dr}{dt}=0.2$, so $r$ is not constant.

For differentiating $\frac{rt}{100}$ you will need to use the Product Rule. Thus $$\frac{dP}{dt}=200 e^{\frac{rt}{100}}\frac{1}{100}\left(r+\frac{dr}{dt}\right).$$

Comment: oh! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Everything should work out fine now.